# ASP.NET MVC 3 with JsonResult: ModelState is always valid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modelstate

I am trying to validate a form using ModelState but my ModelState is always showing as valid.   eg: When I am trying to save a 2 Person formModel each with the same SSN, the ModelState is returning valid. I am using IValidatableObject to validate my formmodel. Any ideas what I might be going wrong? I am using .Net 4.0 with MVC 3.

```
public JsonResult LoadOccupantsDetailedInformation()
{
    //Load the personsFormModel with data
    return new JsonpResult(personsFormModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOccupantsDetailedInformation(
PersonsFormModel personsFormModel)
    {
//This line is always returning true even if I pass 2 persons with the same ssn
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errorList = ModelState.ToDictionary(
                      kvp => kvp.Key,
                      kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                );
            return Json(new { Errors = errorList });
        }
        //Save the data in personsFormModel to database
        return Json(new JsonResultViewModel { Success = true });
    }


public partial class PersonsFormModel : List<PersonFormModel>, IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> Validate(
    ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResults
            = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>();
        if (this.SSNs.Count() > this.SSNs.Distinct().Count())
        {
            validationResults.Add(new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult(
            "All the persons in the household should have a unique SSN\\ITIN number",
                new[] { "SSN" }));
        }
        return validationResults;
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> SSNs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Select(element => element.SSN);
        }
    }
}
    public class PrequalifyOccupantListPersonDetailedFormModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "SSN is required")]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I worked around this issue by manually calling the ValidateViewModel(personsFormModel, this); before checking if the ModelState was valid, in the SaveOccupantsDetailedInformation controller action. I got this function from one of the stackoverflow.com questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I fixed the issue that I was having:

```
***Controller:***
public JsonResult LoadOccupantsDetailedInformation()
{
    //Load the personsFormModel with data
    return new JsonpResult(personsFormModel, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOccupantsDetailedInformation(
PersonsFormModel personsFormModel)
    {
//This line is always returning true even if I pass 2 persons with the same ssn
        if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            var errorList = ModelState.ToDictionary(
                      kvp => kvp.Key,
                      kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                );
            return Json(new { Errors = errorList });
        }
        //Save the data in personsFormModel to database
        return Json(new JsonResultViewModel { Success = true });
    }

***Model:***
public class PersonsFormModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public PersonsFormModel()
    {
        this.Instance = new List<PersonFormModel>();
    }

    public List<PrequalifyOccupantListPersonFormModel> Instance { get; set; }

    public void Add(PersonFormModel personFormModel)
    {
        Instance.Add(personFormModel);
    }

    public IEnumerable<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult> Validate(
    ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var validationResults
            = new List<System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult>();
        if (this.SSNs.Count() > this.SSNs.Distinct().Count())
        {
            validationResults.Add(new System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult(
            "All the persons in the household should have a unique SSN\\ITIN number",
                new[] { "SSN" }));
        }
        return validationResults;
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> SSNs
    {
        get
        {
            return Instance.Select(element => element.SSN);
        }
    }
}

public class PersonFormModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "SSN is required")]
    public string SSN { get; set; }
}

View: 

// Note, I am passing the "Instance" here. 

 var postData = JSON.stringify({ Instance: list });

            RealPage.DataManager.POST({
                url: "/Approval/SaveOccupantsDetailedInformation"
                , data: postData
                , success: function (data) {
                    if (data && data.Success) {

                    } 
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a test to verify you're validation and it looks good.

```
        [Test]
        public void Should_validate_person_form_model()
        {
            var input = new PersonsFormModel();
            input.Add(new PersonFormModel { SSN = "33" });
            input.Add(new PersonFormModel { SSN = "33" });
            _controller.ViewData.ModelState.Clear();

            var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

            bool isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(input,
                new ValidationContext(input, null, null),
                results,true);

            Assert.IsTrue(!isValid, "Cannot have duplicates.");
        }
```

So either it isn't being called or your data is valid.

To test the former can you put a break point within Validate and confirm it is being hit.

To test the latter can you provide the exact data that is posted and the full models involved.

Comment: Yeh, I had written a test case and that worked fine but the Validate method was not being called when the save controller action was called from the view. To work around this problem, we had to change the PersonsFormModel to not inherit from List<PersonFormModel> and pass the List<PersonFormModel> as an array from the UI View. I no longer need to call the ValidateViewModel(personsFormModel, this); when saving the FormModel.

Comment: @AjitGoel so you need anything else, or is that it sorted?

Comment: Also note, that if the model is invalid due to a data annotation required attribute say it would not call the validator but it would return invalid.

Comment: and what's the rest of the partial class?

Comment: Yes dove, I have that sorted out. I have posted the correct answer down below